# How would you make a permanent custom keyboard shortcut in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I found a way to make a custom keyboard shortcut in Eclipse to replace the

```
Run Ant build: Alt + Shift + X, Q
```

I made my own shortcut which is easier, `Alt + F3`.  However, it gets erased when I exit the program. How can I keep it permanently?

Comment: I just tried to set it via Window > Preferences > General > Keys. I was able to do it. It did not reset on restart. I think something is going on with your eclipse. I would reinstall eclipse and try. But be careful with your existing workspaces and projects while you do that.